# Deleting particular text in a file using c#?

Tags: c#, file, string

My text file named test.txt contains

> Fixing the type manager error during checkin of the elements and supporting issues during Checkin/Checkout & merge related problems.

Now i want to remove the text "supporting issues" using c#.

Please anybody let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Naveenkumar.T

Comment: What, exactly, are you asking?  How to open a file?  How to parse a file?  What to do with the data?  At a bare minimum, we need to see the format of said text file.  This isn't too hard, but be really need more information.

Comment: I think he described it clearly - he has a text file, the contents are shown in the question, and he wants to remove two words from it.. ?

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone: Yes, it has been re-formatted to be much more clear now.  When I posted my comment, it was not nearly as clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

if the file is fairly small you can do this:

```
using System.IO; // at the top of the file

string file = "path.txt"; // change to the path

// read the whole file into a string, make a replacement, then write all string to a file
File.WriteAllText(file, File.ReadAllText(file).Replace("supporting issues ",""));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Haha nice, that teaches us to read into questions too much. Good one!